# PHP, ExtJS and never ending ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, extjs

In my JavaScript application (built in ExtJS, if it matters), I have an ajax call to some PHP-script which does some relatively long task. This how this script ends:

```
$guid = getGUID();
file_put_contents('tmp/' . $guid . '.json', json_encode($olap_data));   
$res = new stdClass;
$res->success = true;
$res->guid = $guid;
echo json_encode($res);
```

When I make this ajax call, I see that in about 30 seconds (not so long) there appears a json file in `tmp` folder. However, the script still never changes its status. I see this picture for dozens of minutes in the console:

[image]

The important row is marked in blue. As you can see its status never gets changed. I thought, this is because of ExtJS and I applied these overrides to increase timeouts:

```
Ext.define("Ext.override.data.Connection",{override:"Ext.data.Connection", timeout:30000000});
Ext.define("Ext.override.Ajax",{override:"Ext.Ajax", timeout:30000000});
Ext.define("Ext.override.data.proxy.Ajax",{override:"Ext.data.proxy.Ajax", timeout:30000000});
Ext.define("Ext.override.form.action.Action",{override:"Ext.form.action.Action", timeout:30000});
```

But it does not help. So what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong with that. In fact the whole problem is with `ExtJS`. Since version `ExtJS 5`, now we have to add this line of code to increase timeouts:

```
Ext.Ajax.setTimeout(big_number_for_long_requests);
```